# Eliminating duplicates in an ERD Diagram

Tags: erd

I am creating an ERD model that is for incoming packages and who receives them. Since it would be useful to know who accepted the package and who the package is intended for my thought was to add an employee table and then an accepter table (who accepted the package) and an orderer table (who ordered the package). My problem is thinking out the relationships. Because the orderer table would draw from the Employee table I need to figure out what relationship they are, but all I am coming up with is a 1:1 relationship.

Each employee can be one orderer.
Each orderer is one employee.

I am struggling to understand if there is just a major flaw in my thinking or if I am just approaching the problem wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.